# How do I unclog my bath tub drain?

Tags: bathroom

Our tub drain was clogged. We have used Drano (liquid and granular) unsuccessfully. We have used a snake-didn't work. Noticed there is a hardened substance that you can scrape. ?? Accumulation of chemicals we used? Not sure.
What do we do now? Trying to avoid a plumber which will cost $$$

Thanks,
Denise

Comment: How long of a snake did you use?

Comment: Post a picture of the drain

Comment: Might try hot/boiling water; it's quickened my drains in the past by melting soap scum/animal fat, but i've never used it on a complete stop. Still, the cost/benefit ratio is good enough to try it.

Comment: How severe is the clog (complete, very slow, etc.)?  Can you tell more about the snake attempt (did it not deploy?  Did it deploy but didn't help at all, helped a little bit)?  Did the clog appear all at once, or has it been getting worse over time?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Ecnerwal removing the over flow cap is the easiest way to snake a tub. Most 1/4 inch auger drain snakes have a 25 foot cable. If just the tub is not draining and the sink in the same room is draining correctly that tells you the clog is not to far in the tub drain (since both drains connect to a main drain pipe).

Snaking to clear a blockage in a pipe takes acute sensory perception. Knowing if the snake stopped advancing because of a fitting or the clog is a skill.

Try the snake again through the over flow drain. Extend the cable the full length. When you meet resistance ream the snake back and forth several times. When you retract the cable note what (if anything) is stuck on the auger tip.

When executed properly there will be a noted increase in (or complete) draining. You may need to re-snake several times depending on the type of blockage. Once it is cleared run hot water for a few minutes to remove residual clog and caustic drain opener. ***You must be careful when working with water that has chemicals from a drain opener still dissolved in it. Don't let the snake splash any water on your skin or face.***

Answer (score 0):

The stock tub drain setup tends to require removing the overflow plate (which is also where the lever for the tub stopper is in most tubs with a lever controlled stopper) and pulling up the stopper, if it's that common lever-controlled stopper setup.

In many cases, the clog is right there, accumulated on the stopper itself. If not, feeding the snake in via the overflow gives it a straight shot into the tub trap, as opposed to the hard right angle at the usual stopper location if fed in via the tub drain. That is true even if you have a "in the tub" stopper - the hard right angle is still there.